# Slit slider fadein fadeout effect

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, jquery-effects

I am trying to change the transition effect of [this slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/) by putting fadeout / fadein

I would like change this without css3 (only jquery for working in IE) but I don't see how to implement this effect in the js..

If someone could just help me and let me know what I'm doing wrong ..!

My attempt is here : [my implementation](http://www.artsx.fr/serenites)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try the functions **`fadeIn()`** and **`fadeOut()`**.

Here is fadeIn() : http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Here is fadeOut() : http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: i know how it works, but i dont know where i cant put this parameters in this plugin.